# New TwitchTV API call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a beginner to programming and for a challenge I need to get the status (Streaming live/Off-line) for a given number of channels.

I wrote an ajax request but I am still getting 401 as a response. Below my code and a screen shot of the response.

I have even made the token request as `async: false`to make sure the token is back before triggering the API call

```
$("document").ready(function() {

var aoathToken = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials",
    error: function() {
        console.log("Check your request!!")
    },

    success: function(token) {
        console.log(token);
    }
})

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=freecodecamp",
    contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
    crossDomain: true,
    header: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Client-ID": "MY CLIENT ID",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + aoathToken,
    },
    data: {"user_login": "myUserID"},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    },
    error: function(json) {
        window.alert(json.status + " " + json.message);
    },
})
```

[image: API response]

Comment: You did swap client_id and client_secret to your values?

Comment: Nope, my client_id and my client_secret are correct. I thought of it & checked it's fine.

Comment: Check your headers in the request and see if they are being included properly. I worry your header section is interfering with the URL tokens.

Comment: Actually I missed the "s" in headers key. But now I am getting "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."